# Express assinging more fields to middleware function

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to make a middleware that can take more than request response and next parameters ?

For example:

```
app.get("/", myMiddleware(parameter), function(req,res){...})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: For different routes I want the middleware to behave a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define the middleware with different signature.

e.g.

```
var customMiddleware = function(arg1){
    return function(req, res, next){
        //do whatever you want to do with req, res, next and arg1
    }
}

app.get('/', customMiddleware(arg1), function(req, res){
    //some code
});
```